# When assigning a readonly NSString property of an object, do you still need to [copy]?

Tags: nsstring, copy, properties, readonly

I have MyClass setup as below. If the NSString property is readonly it should already be set to copy and autorelease. Do I still need to copy it like below?

```
MyClass *myClass = [[MyClass alloc] init];
NSString *assignStr = [myClass.returnStr copy];
...
[myClass release];
[assignStr release];
```

or

```
MyClass *myClass = [[MyClass alloc] init];
NSString *assignStr = myClass.returnStr;
...
[myClass release];
```

MyClass.h

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {    
@private
    NSString *returnStr;
}
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *returnStr;
@end
```

MyClass.m

```
@implementation MyClass
@synthesize returnStr;
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the code you provided

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {    
@private
    NSString *returnStr;
}
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *returnStr;
@end
```

Your property setter is defined with [simple assignment](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1)

So you can use both code snippet to adjust the assignStr value, it would be correct in term of memory management ; the logical one should be to use the classical assign pattern.

But in fact it is more about, how you are handling the master value (the value you are returning as read-only) and what you want to achieve with it (sorry this is not that clear to me in the provided sample, which does not seems to match 100% your thread title)